# Conda remove fails due to disk space

Tags: python, conda

`conda remove --name {my_env} --all -y`

seems to complete almost successfully

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Rolling back transaction: done
```

but is followed by
`[Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded()`

I need disk space to remove conda envs but I can only free up disk space by removing them. Should I just `rm -rf {path to env}`?

Comment: Maybe try to clean your conda:
conda clean --all

Comment: this also fails

Comment: i solved this by manually removing files

Comment: `conda env remove -n {my_env}` might be a cleaner removal. Also, you could add `-v` flags (more for more verbosity) to see what specific transaction fails.